# clicking on label 'for' both anchor tag and input tag

Tags: css

I cannot get this work, looks like not possible, that's why i'm asking...

This is the CSS used:

```
label.btn {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
label.btn>input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
label.btn>input[type=checkbox]:checked~b {
    background:red;
}
/* not relevant, just for testing purpose */
#divtest { 
    margin-top:1500px
}
```

Following HTML code will check the input, and then style for `<b>` tag is applied:

```
<a href="#divtest" id="anchor">
    <label class="btn">
        <input type="checkbox"/><b>Click should scroll to '#divetest' element and check input for styling!</b>
    </label>
</a>
```

[DEMO styling](http://jsfiddle.net/7Pgj3/)

If i add attribute 'for' to the label to target the anchor tag, the default browser scrolling works, but then no more styling applied:

```
<label class="btn" for="anchor">
```

[DEMO anchor](http://jsfiddle.net/7Pgj3/1/)

Now, the obvious question:

**Can i get these both behaviours working together in pure CSS?**

Comment: What are your expecting from an input type:checkbox INSIDE an anchor. On anchor click, browser will scroll to #divtest, on label, browser will set focus to 'input'  and click on the 'input' will be like clicking the outmost anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `input` element inside an `a` violates common sense as well as HTML5 CR. Nesting two interactive elements raises the issue which element is activated on mouse click.

Instead of such construct, use valid and sensible HTML markup. Then please formulate the styling question in terms of desired or expected rendering vs. actual rendering, instead of saying that “this” “does not work”.

Comment: This is great and valid info, thx. I didn't want being too vague in my question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work since the Input:checkbox is INSIDE the `<label>`. Browsers will set focus on the input upon a click on the label.

Comment: That's what i see and think, not possible! I was looking for a guru ninja with special trick, if any...  Anyway, thx for your answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol and then how will you apply style like using the `:checked` pseudo class? I've already trying to use `:active` but it is not behaviour i'm expecting. If fact my example was quite wrong, i should have post it using radio button, not checkbox as i want style to be persistant. Hope you understand what i mean?!

Comment: :checked applies to the checkbox no matter what, so you might just as well use `input[type=checkbox]:checked` instead of `label.btn>input[type=checkbox]:checked`. Or even `label.btn+input[type=checkbox]:checked` if you need to relate the checkbox to the label. I don't see how this would be different when using radiobuttons, but maybe I just don't know what you mean.